# Python NameError The class of the name is not defined but it actually is

Tags: python, class

I was playing with classes and I thought to create a class called Container which is meant to group all things that can hold other things.

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

class Container(object):
    def __init__(self, name, volume):
        self.name = name
        self.max_volume = volume

hands = Container('HANDS', 2)
```

I started from this point and then I wanted to test if everything was ok but if in the python console I call `hands.name` it says that `hands` is not defined. This happens when I import it as a module too.

I don't get what I am doint wrong! Can you please explain me how to make it work?

I get from the python console:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'hands' is not defined
```

Comment: Works fine for me. Are you sure you're using `hands` as in your code and not `hand` as in the error message?

Comment: are you importing this from a separate file when using the console?

Comment: @EricAppelt this is a separate file

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Assuming this is the `container.py` file:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

class Container(object):
    def __init__(self, name, volume):
        self.name = name
        self.max_volume = volume

hands = Container('HANDS', 2)
```

and this is your execution command in the interpreter:

```
>>> import container
```

Then, the `hands` instance is accessible in the following manner:

```
>>> container.hands.name
```

To avoid the `container` prefix, you can also do this:

```
>>> from container import hands
>>> hands.name
```

Comment: Thank you. This was my real problem I forgot to call the module!

Comment: I will! I have to wait 4 minutes though