# Running Python program from command line

Tags: python, python-3.x, command-line-interface

I am using Windows Powershell to import Python file and create instance of one of the class defined with in file as follows:

```
import random
class RandomWalker:
    def __init__(self):
        self.position = 0

    def walk(self, n):
        self.position = 0
        for i in range(n):
            yield self.position
            self.position += 2*random.randint(0,1) -1
```

This file is `randomWalk.py`

So, I run the below command on Python command line:

```
>>> import randomWalk
```

But when I try to create an instance of the class it throws an error:

```
>>> walker = RandomWalker()

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
NameError: name 'RandomWalker' is not defined
```

What am I missing?
I tried to google, I assume we can create an instance of class on Python command line interface.

Comment: have to try ```from randomWalk import RandomWalker```

Comment: Also found this post which ans the question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30562669/python-nameerror-the-class-of-the-name-is-not-defined-but-it-actually-is

Comment: I assume same need not be done in python notebooks. I was following below link for reference which directly access the class :
https://www.cs.bgu.ac.il/~ppl172/wiki.files/practice/VectorizingLoops.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should try:

```
walker = randomWalk.RandomWalker()
```

Answer (score 4):

You are importing only the module, not the class. With the code you provided try:

```py
import randomWalk

walker = randomWalk.RandomWalker()
```

or for importing the class directly:

```py
from randomWalk import RandomWalker

walker = RandomWalker()
```